# Can we represent IPV6 Address CIDR notations to 16-bit hex field (eight groups of four hexadecimal digits)

Tags: networking, ip, ipv6

I am new to IPv6. I have a doubt, whether we can represent IPV6 Address CIDR notations to 16-bit hex field (eight groups of four hexadecimal digits)?.

my system address is `inet6 addr: xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64.`

is there any way to find the equivalent address in the format of 16-bit hex field (eight groups of four hexadecimal digits)(`eg:2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `::` bit means that all the missing groups are `0000`, so when expanding `xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx` it becomes `xxxx:0000:0000:0000:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx`. Just add groups of zeroes until you are back to eight groups.